# here, for a non prime number, the break statement in the inner loop is executed but the else statement of the outer loop is not executed, why?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

```
L = []
nmax = 30

for n in range(2, nmax):
    for factor in L:
        if n % factor == 0:
            break
    else: # no break
        L.append(n)
print(L)
```

Does the else in the outer loop work if the if statement is not execute din the inner loop...are they really connected inspite being in different loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The else isn't connected to the if statement but to the break statement.

The for/else syntax means that the else block will be executed if there is **no** break **encountered** inside the for loop.

Here is an example for ppl to understand it :

```py
fruits = ["Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Strawberry"]

def searchFruit(wanted):
    for fruit in fruits:
        if fruit == wanted:
            break
    else: # Can't find the wanted fruit
        return False
    # Found the wanted fruit
    return True

searchFruit("Tomato") # Output : False
```

Comment: once break is encountered in the loop, shouldn't we jump to the outer loop and execute the else statement... but it doesnt happen, why?

Comment: No, if the break is encountered, the else statement will NOT be executed ^^ : You'll only jump in the outer loop and do nothing

Comment: but why.... the break statement takes us out of the inner loop ,and since else is in the outer loop, shouldn't it be executed

Comment: This else statement is related to your for loop, it will only be executed is the for loop ends normally.. That's how it works